# How to remove nameserver IPs in WHM 11.30.2?

Tags: hosting, nameserver, dedicated-server

As explained on this page: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/NsIps

When visiting: **WHM > DNS Functions > Nameserver IPs**

You see a table with 3 columns showing Nameserver, IP, & No. Zones (which is apparently how many domain names are using said nameservers). It only shows you information, doesn't allow you to change anything.

I used to be able to click on: **WHM > Networking Setup > Nameserver IPs** ... but that just redirects to **WHM > DNS Functions > Nameserver IPs** now (my WHM updates daily to the latest stable build, working with 11.30.2 at the moment).

How can I get back the functionality of the old **WHM > Networking Setup > Nameserver IPs** which had a little red X you could remove nameservers with and a text box you could add nameservers with?

Comment: I had many problems when I had my WHM updated daily, IMO you should only update when a security bug is putting your server at risk. To monitor that you should check http://www.us-cert.gov/current/ regularly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nameserver configuration should be in

WHM | Server Configuration | Basic cPanel & WHM Setup

Apparently, the Nameserver IPs section is [just for display](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/how-add-nameservers-there-no-option-anymore-nameserver-ips-page-237041.html#post975402).